# userinit and running another program

Tags: c#, winlogon

I need to start a program every time the computer starts.

Company rules do not allow for the run registry key to be touched.

I read somewhere that appending an executable to the end of the userinit entry in the winlogon registry will allow a program to be started.

I think this is true, as my application does indeed start....   BUT, and here is the crazy thing....    the application starts off the screen...  way lower than the start button.

I have the program set to start in screen center...  but it does not want to display in the correct location until i do a alt-tab to bring it to the front, and then it will be displayed in the correct location.

So my question is

using the userinit, and appending the executable to the end of the values line, does indeed start the application, but how do I force it to center on the screen when the screen has not been established yet?

thank you

Comment: Come to find out....   its the video driver....  updated it and all is well now.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to modify the registry for this. In fact, you probably *shouldn't* be modifying the registry for this. The company policy makes some degree of sense.

Instead, just add a shortcut to the application's executable to your Startup folder. (Or, if you want to make it run at startup for *all* users, add it to the All Users Startup folder.)

It's very easy to do by hand—just drag the shortcut into the folder. The typical paths are something like:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp (for a single user)

%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp (for all users)
```

But it's not terribly difficult to do this programmatically, either. You just need to retrieve the path of the folder—don't hardcode it! To do that from C#, call the [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) function, specifying either the `SpecialFolder.Startup` or `SpecialFolder.CommonStartup` values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just talking about the location of a WinForm application, maybe you can try this:

```
void SetLocation(Point location) {
    var context=SynchronizationContext.Current;

    (new Thread(
        () => {
            SendOrPostCallback d=dummy => {
                this.Location=location;
            };

            for(; ; Thread.Sleep(0))
                try {
                    context.Send(d, null);
                }
                catch(InvalidAsynchronousStateException ex) {
                    break;
                }
        })).Start();
}
```

For example, invoke it in your form load or some event handler you wish to:

```
SetLocation(Point.Empty);
```

It executes forever for setting the location of the form; you might want to write a method that terminate this thread once it has already set to the location you want.

Answer (score 0):

It was the video driver...  updated it, and the dialog is displaying in the center of the screen as coded.